# build.sbt Scoping does not work

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

Hello I'm trying to set a value depending on the running task in my build.sbt:

```
ngScalaModule in fastOptJS := "./plugintest2-fastopt.js"
ngScalaModule in fullOptJS := "./plugintest2-opt.js"
```

Now when i run the task fastOptJS or fullOptJS the value ngScalaModule is not used when I try this without scoping:

```
ngScalaModule in fastOptJS := "./plugintest2-fastopt.js"
```

The value is used.
My question is, weather I have done something totally wrong or does the plugin which provieds ngScalaModule has to explicit implement the scoping.

The value ngScalaModule is provided by an other sbt plugin as the two tasks, just in case it makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: What plugin provides `ngScalaModule`?

Comment: https://github.com/jokade/angulate2

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of [`Angulate2Plugin`](https://github.com/jokade/angulate2/blob/master/plugin/src/main/scala/de/surfice/angulate2/sbtplugin/Angulate2Plugin.scala), we can indeed see that the setting `ngScalaModule` is only ever read scoped only by the *project* (and not the configuration nor the task, which are the other two scope axes in sbt).

Therefore, the setting that you define `ngScalaModule in fastOptJS` is not used by anything. angulate2 will only read `ngScalaModule` (unscoped).

That means that angulate2 would have to be changed for you to be able to specify a different `ngScalaModule` in `fastOptJS` versus `fullOptJS`. Note that angulate2 itself depends on [`SJSXPlugin`](https://github.com/jokade/sjsx/blob/master/plugin/src/main/scala/sjsx/sbtplugin/SJSXPlugin.scala) (by the same author) for its `sjsxSnippets` settings, which is also only scoped per project. So this might have some deep consequences.